# Passwords cannot be typed in form

Tags: python, html, django

Passwords cannot be typed in form.
Im making user regist web site.
I wrote in views.py

```
def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)
```

in forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

in regist.html

```html
    <main>
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="heading col-lg-6 col-md-12">                     
                      <h1>WEB SITE</h1>                     
                    </div>
                
                                         <div class="heading col-lg-6 col-md-12">                     
                    <h2>NEW REGISTRATION</h2>
                
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">                     
                      <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                        <label for="id_username">USER NAME</label>
                                             {{ regist_form.username }}                     
                      </div>                                          
                      <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                        <label for="id_email">EMAIL</label>
                                              {{ regist_form.email }}
                      </div>                                          
                      <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                        <label for="id_password">PASSWORD</label>                     
                         {{ regist_form.password1 }}                     
                      </div>                                          
                      <div class="form-group-lg">
                        <label for="id_password">PASSWORD（CONFROMATION）</label>                     
                         {{ regist_form.password2 }}
                         <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>                     
                      </div>                                          
                      <div class="form-group-lg">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SUBMIT</button>                     
                        <input name="next" type="hidden"/>                     
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      {% csrf_token %}                     
                    </form>                     
                    </div>
                    </div>
        </main>
```

I really cannot understand why only passwords cannot be typed in form.Username&Email can be typed.Because I cannot type passwords,so I cannot put SEND button.How should I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "passwords cannot be typed"?  The password input fields are missing altogether?  They are present, but unable to accept input?  Please be specific.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but I notice both of the password fields have labels with `for="id_password"`, but you don't appear to have any input fields with that id.

Comment: @JohnGordon I can write all fields(Username&Email&Password1&Password2).But when I put SUBMIT button,Password1&Password2 filed is disappear.

Comment: @JohnGordon In ur 2nd message,so how should I do it?I can understand what u a saying,but i cannot fix it.

Comment: Perhaps it's because you are only defining two fields in the Meta?  `fields = ('username', 'email',)`

Comment: @JohnGordon i added fields like fields = ('username', 'email','password1','password1',) ,but same error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to include  tag for password.

```
<Input type="password" name="password" >
```

Comment: Presumably `{{ regist_form.password1 }} ` expands to the actual password input field.